# Need help in web scraping using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, webdriverwait

Code trials:

```
from gettext import find
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
path="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get("https://targetstudy.com/school/state-board-schools-in-himachal-pradesh.html")
section=driver.find_element_by_class_name("section")
print(section.text)
driver.quit()
```

I was able to write this but after that I wasn't able to extract the desired texts. See pic I want the highlighted texts:

[these highlighted texts i want to extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5drLp.png)

In this excel format

[my desired excel format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWOwS.png)

There are 25 entries in 1 page so I also have to click on the next button with the help of Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

The desired texts of each item is within the following element:

```
<div class="media-body">
```

---

### Solution

To extract the desired texts you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://targetstudy.com/school/state-board-schools-in-himachal-pradesh.html")
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='media-body'][.//a/h4]")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['Aadhar Public School\nlocation_on Bir (Bagera)\n  Hamirpur - 176110, Himachal Pradesh, India\nphone_iphone 9418125341', 'Aakash Model School\nlocation_on Lahra Galore\n  Hamirpur - 177026, Himachal Pradesh, India\nphone (01972)-243201\nphone_iphone 9418118090', 'Aastha Public School - Banuti\nlocation_on Banuti\n  Shimla - 171011, Himachal Pradesh, India\nphone (0177)-2802404\nphone_iphone 9418022024', 'Aastha Public School - Hatpang\nlocation_on Hatpang\n  Kangra - 176022, Himachal Pradesh, India\nphone_iphone 9459068853', 'Abhi Public School\nlocation_on Goli (Dalhousie)\n  Chamba - 176305, Himachal Pradesh, India\nphone_iphone 9418410844, 9418093564', 'Abhinav Vidya Mandir High School\nlocation_on Haroli\n  Una - 177220, Himachal Pradesh, India\nphone (01975)-284209\nphone_iphone 9418537523', 'Abhishek Public High School\nlocation_on Rait\n  Kangra - 176208, Himachal Pradesh, India\nphone (01892)-238524\nphone_iphone 9816297368', 'ACE Public School\nlocation_on Sarah\n  Kangra - 176215, Himachal Pradesh, India\nphone_iphone 9418427824', 'Adarsh Bal Jyoti Public School\nlocation_on Beru Thona\n  Mandi - 175049, Himachal Pradesh, India\nphone_iphone 9857560105, 9817163967', 'Adarsh Bal Mandir High School\nlocation_on Bhawarna\n  Kangra - 176083, Himachal Pradesh, India\nphone (01894)-247115', 'Adarsh Bal Vidya Mandir School\nlocation_on Rajpur\n  Sirmaur - 173025, Himachal Pradesh, India\nphone_iphone 9816235897, 9816208863', 'Adarsh Bharti Public School\nlocation_on NH-154, Jassur\n  Kangra - 177201, Himachal Pradesh, India\nphone (01893)-226945\nphone_iphone 9418476945', 'Adarsh Bharti Public School\nlocation_on Nagrota Surian\n  Kangra - 176027, Himachal Pradesh, India\nphone_iphone 9816461493', 'Adarsh Bharti Public School\nlocation_on Samkehar\n  Kangra - 176023, Himachal Pradesh, India\nphone_iphone 9418013823', 'Adarsh Bharti Public School\nlocation_on Village Dak & PO Dahab, Tehsil Nurpur\n  Kangra - 176051, Himachal Pradesh, India\nphone_iphone 9418356123, 9816923352', 'Adarsh Bhartiya Model School\nlocation_on Gharan (Bhojpur)\n  Kangra - 176402, Himachal Pradesh, India\nphone (01893)-245117\nphone_iphone 9816636653', 'Adarsh Gyan Public School\nlocation_on Tatwali\n  Kangra - 176058, Himachal Pradesh, India\nphone_iphone 9816789311, 9872242147', 'Adarsh High School\nlocation_on Ghumarwin\n  Bilaspur - 174021, Himachal Pradesh, India\nphone (01978)-255605\nphone_iphone 9418042523', 'Adarsh High School\nlocation_on Kuthera\n  Bilaspur - 174026, Himachal Pradesh, India\nphone (01978)-275690\nphone_iphone 9817050966', 'Adarsh Jyoti Primary School\n\n  Mandi - 175001, Himachal Pradesh, India\nphone_iphone 9817567850', 'Adarsh Jyoti Public School\nlocation_on Beru Thona\n  Mandi - 175049, Himachal Pradesh, India\nphone_iphone 9857560105, 9817163967', 'Adarsh Model High School\nlocation_on Chatta Khad\n  Kangra - 176025, Himachal Pradesh, India\nphone_iphone 9816123223', 'Adarsh Model School\nlocation_on Kariyara\n  Kangra - 177017, Himachal Pradesh, India\nphone_iphone 9218949303, 9736590988', 'Adarsh Primary School\nlocation_on Umari-Gander\n  Kangra - 176097, Himachal Pradesh, India\nphone_iphone 9816123581', 'Adarsh Public School\nlocation_on Mandrighat\n  Bilaspur - 174013, Himachal Pradesh, India\nphone (01907)-283019\nphone_iphone 9817304028, 9418059027']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Find where you can access the next webpage from the current web page and use

```
.click
```

on the element

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).